# Can't upload image from canvas to folder using spring MultipartFile class

Tags: spring

I'm uploading an image from a `Canvas` to a server through an Ajax call and using Spring MultipartFile storing it inside a folder, but I get a `NullpointerException` at this line:

```
MultipartFile multipartImage = uploadImage.getFormData();
```

of

```
@RequestMapping(value="/visitorvisits/fileUpload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String save(@ModelAttribute VisitorImageUpload uploadImage,HttpServletRequest request)
{
    logger.info("Inside controller");
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("formData"));
    MultipartFile multipartImage=uploadImage.getFormData();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is your configuration in `applicationContext.xml` ?

`<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />`

do you have defined that bean in context file?
To properly usage of uploading pictures you have to declare that bean into your application context.

Try to change your controller method declaration.
`@ModelAttribute VisitorImageUpload uploadImage` to `@RequestParam('file) MultipartFile uploadImage`